# Odoo 10 many invoices templates

Tags: docker, odoo

I got many xml inherit from account.invoices report to replaces based in the enterprise that are using the system. How will the best way to make custom invoices for N clients?

I was thinking make a recipe for docker and build the branches depends of the client with the invoice for that client.

I don't know if this will be a bad choice because if I have N clients all with custom invoices, it will be N docker instances with odoo. Or make a wizard to choice the type of invoice to use in One Odoo instance.

This question is more technical than programming, I want to know your toughs about it.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is build templates for a group of client or just for a client, you could add a template to the group of clients or add the template for a client, then inherit the proper method to select the template asigned to the group or asigned to the client. I hope this advice will helpfull for you.

Comment: Great, i thinks this approach more in terms of hardware usage. Thanks for answer, now I have more clear this situation.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.